# ¿como hago para centrar esos dos divs resaltados si estan dentro de un foreach?

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo de esta parte

```html
@if(\App\Child::get(100, 8)->count())
                <div class="flex justify-content-center">
                    <?php
                        $iterador = 1;
                    ?>
                    <div class="row">
                      @foreach(\App\Child::get(100, 8) as &$child)
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 400px">
                                    @if($iterador === 1)
                                      <h3 style="font-size: 25px; margin:0px; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">PICADORA DE FORRAJE OFICIAL</h3>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($iterador === 2)
                                      <h3 style="font-size: 25px; margin:0px; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">SEMBRADORA OFICIAL</h3>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($iterador === 3)
                                      <h3 style="font-size: 25px; margin:0px; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">BALANCEADO OFICIAL</h3>
                                    @endif
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                                      @if($iterador === 4)
                                      <h3 style="font-size: 25px; margin:0px; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">SUPLEMENTO NUTRICIÓN ANIMAL OFICIAL</h3>
                                      @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                      <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="{{ url($child->src) }}" alt="">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                $iterador++;
                            ?>
                          </div>
                      @endforeach
                      <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 400px;">
                          <h3 style="font-size: 25px; margin:0px 10px 0px 0px; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">LUBRICANTE OFICIAL</h3>
                          <img src="{{ asset('img/lubricante.png') }}" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: no acabas hace poco de hacer la misma pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246673/como-hago-para-que-lubricantes-este-al-lado-de-suplemento-nutricional-animal

Comment: no, esta es diferente

Comment: Agrega `justify-content-center` al div `row`

Comment: Gracias de veras me salvaste uff